# Jquery UI Autocomplete Ajax JSONP return is broken in JQ UI Version 1.8.6

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jsonp

Ive been using the code below for my auto-completes on my form for a while , but after updating jquery ui to version 1.8.6 from 1.8rc3 it has broken the formatting of the JSONP return. The returned data is no longer formatted html, but instead it is a string. Any Ideas?

**Update: JS Fiddle included, using the jquery ui demo and html in the data**

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/ejLPg/

```
 $("#companyname").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: turl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    maxRows: 9,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: "<span class='ui-menu-item-title'>" + item.name.toLowerCase() + "</span><span class='ui-menu-item-subtitle'>" + item.address1.toLowerCase() + '&nbsp;' + item.post_code.toLowerCase() + '</span>',
                            value: item.name_id
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 50,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            LoadGivenCompany(ui.item.value);
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        },
        focus: function () { return false }
    });
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out by using the .data(), after the autocomplete allows you to format the data

```
$(function() {
function log(message) {
    $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").attr("scrollTop", 0);
}

$("#city").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                featureClass: "P",
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data.geonames, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.name,
                        test: 'hahahah'
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function() {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
})       
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.test + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/ejLPg/3

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code of autocomplete of version 1.8.6 and found out that item creation uses text method instead of the html method. They suggest at jQuery.ui to change style using the theme roller of by altering the widget specific classes in the css file.
See [Autocomplete#theming](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#theming).

What i would do is find the place that they push the text in the element and change the method call back to html and test it out.

Comment: thats pretty sound advice thanks, altough i think may aswell roll back the jquery version, i just thought i might be doing something wrong, im suprised i couldnt find anyone else with the same issue.